# Matching specific string format in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I know there are many similar questions on SO about regex and matching, but I just cant get this to work!

I need to check if my string is in the specific format of:

13:30 - 14:00

2 numbers, colon, 2 numbers, space, dash, space, 2 numbers, colon, 2 numbers

This is my best effort so far...

```
$string = "13:30 - 14:00";
$regex = '^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} - [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$';
if (preg_match($regex, $string)) {
echo "matched pattern";
}
```

I am a regex noob, and I'm not sure why this isnt working.

Can someone help me to get this regex matching working?

Comment: Watch out that of 25:71 is not validated.

Comment: The strings will always be properly formatted as far as times are concerned, so I only need to check the format pattern, not validate the times.

Comment: OK then you can go with strlen($string) == 13 and $string[6] == '-' XD

Comment: No, because then "AB:cD - Ef:11" would pass, which doesnt fit my original question at all. @u_mulder answer was spot on and answers my question fully.

Comment: What I mean is that if the other string is guaranteed to be properly formatted don't do any validation, if it is not guaranteed then do all the validation, that's the spirit of design by contract. That way you don't repeat the same job that the other has done.

Comment: I am not doing any validation, and my original question doesnt mention validation. I need to find these lines in a large file with many other lines of text, so that I can find and extract the times only.

Comment: But if you can expect to have "AB:cD - Ef:11" you can also expect to have "99:99 - 77:77" some day. If you don't control the source then you should perform full validation. Now if you are happy like that so be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**: regexp should start/end with `/` (or `#`)

**Second**: `-` is a special symbol and should be escaped with `\`

```
$string = "13:30 - 14:00";
$regex = '/^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} \- [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$/';
if (preg_match($regex, $string)) {
    echo "matched pattern";
}
```

Comment: Bullseye! Thank you so much!

Comment: Downvote wasnt from me. This was the first and most useful answer, with explanation as to why my regex wasnt working.

Comment: @u_mulder I didn't downvote but still this can be improved because 13:61 will pass this regex.

Comment: My original question only asks to match the pattern. I dont need to validate the time, just pattern match. So this answer fully answers the question that I asked.

Comment: @Richard If you [design by contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) you don't need to validate the pattern at all, or very slightly.

Comment: The hyphen isn't a special regex character and doesn't need to be escaped. You only need to escape `-`  in special situations inside a character class. About the pattern delimiters, writting that a pattern should start and end with `/` or `#` isn't false but inexact. The pattern delimiter can be any character except an alphanumeric, a white-space or a backslash. In addition you can also use paired brackets like `<>`, `()`, `[]`, `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $string = "13:30 - 14:00";    
    $regex = '/^([0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])|(2[0-3]:[0-5][0-9])|(24:00) \- ([0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])|(2[0-3]:[0-5][0-9])|(24:00)$/';    
    if(preg_match($regex, $string)){
        echo "matched pattern";
    }
```

As it seems like time, and for that it must be checked ! `13:70` is not a valid time i guess

Comment: `-` is a special symbol in regexps.

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked it!

Comment: @DominiqueLorre is that ok now ?

Comment: Ye we have similar answers now.

Comment: @u_mulder: no, it's false.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to accept 13:71 or 25:12 you need to extend the regex like this:

```
$string = "13:30 - 14:00";
$regex = '/^([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9] \- ([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/';
if (preg_match($regex, $string)) {
    echo "matched pattern";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may try it like this:

```
<?php

    $strTime    = "13:30 - 14:00";
    $time       = '(\d{2})(:)(\d{2})';
    $rx         = '#^' . $time . '( \- )' . $time . '$#';

    if (preg_match($rx, $strTime)) {
        echo "Pattern was found...";
        // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO WHEN PATTERN IS MATCHED.
    }
```

Comment: Your answer isn't wrong but doesn't explain what was the initial problem. There's no need to put capture groups everywhere.